# Saving high dimensional numpy array in mysql database

Tags: python, sql, numpy

I am currently trying to save **two** dimensional numpy array that has **(1200, 128)** in mysql database for each entry of the data. When I try to take the value from this column with sql query , it takes too long. Should I save this kind of numpy array in database? If I shouldn't, please tell me the other options to save this kind of data for fast retrieval of the value.

Comment: Could you explain the context and purpose of saving the array? Are you storing a tensorflow embedding? Is it useful to be able to get a single item of the array? What are the contents of the array, is it ints, floats, bools, objs?

Comment: Yes. They are  embedding data from deep neural framework. Actually I am trying to get all values from this column where these numpy array are saved.( by using select colname from imagetable). It takes so much time for operation of this query. The type of the content of the array are float32.